# Detecting where mono is installed on Windows

Tags: c#, mono

How can i get a directory or even some more info about it from c# run-time?

The recipe from here:
http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/mattward/archive/2005/10/17/DetectingWhereMonoIsInstalled.aspx
doesn't work any more i guess.

Comment: what you want to do ?

Comment: i want to find the path of mono /bin folder and determine the version of mono installed on particular machine.

Comment: and the profiles information may be